# Arithmetic operations on Pandas series to create new series

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have the following Pandas dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

such that I have the following dataframe

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    |         a |        b |        c |        d |
|----+-----------+----------+----------+----------|
|  0 | 0.462955  | 0.605148 | 0.481413 | 0.848894 |
|  1 | 0.341476  | 0.611664 | 0.419806 | 0.6367   |
|  2 | 0.0773736 | 0.795014 | 0.635595 | 0.154184 |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Say that I want to modify column `d` such that `d = a * b / c`. 
I can use `groupby` and `apply` to obtain the following

```
df.groupby(['a','b','c']).apply(lambda x: x['a'] * x['b'] / x['c'])

a         b         c          
0.077374  0.795014  0.635595  2    0.096780
0.341476  0.611664  0.419806  1    0.497535
0.462955  0.605148  0.481413  0    0.581946
dtype: float64
```

which is somewhat what I am looking for since it contains the desired values, but it is still far from the desired result.

Can you help me out?

EDIT: The method should be workable also in the case where I have a very large filtering.

Comment: Have you tried `df["D"] = df["A"]*df["B"]/df["C"]` ?

Comment: Yes, and that works fine, but in the case I have a very large filtering, the whole expression becomes rather large, hence why I have decided to use `groupby`.

Comment: Do you mean there are a lot of duplicate combinations of a, b and c?

Comment: It depends on how many groups you have, that you might or might not gain any performance. I'd say usually you don't.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need `groupby` or any function (if I'm not misunderstanding something) you can simply define:

```
df['d'] = df['a'] * df['b'] / df['c']
```

Example:

```
data = {'a':[0.462955,0.341476,0.0773736],'b':[0.605148,0.611664,0.795014],'c':[0.481413,0.419806,0.635595]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['d'] = df['a'] * df['b'] / df['c']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c         d
0  0.462955  0.605148  0.481413  0.581946
1  0.341476  0.611664  0.419806  0.497536
2  0.077374  0.795014  0.635595  0.096780
```